# Python converting to HTML table

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

*Python3*

Hi All,

I am trying to extract some data from REST-APIs using python 3 and want to convert the same to an HTML table.

The tricky part of this is, based on the 1st column name I want to perform a rowspan for the other rows with similar item name in the first column.

This is what my RAW output looks like

```
dvTest jdeais1 running Login:Passed , Form Service App:Passed , Form Service UBE:Passed
dvTest jdejas1 running Login:Passed , Interactive App:Passed , UBE:Passed
dvTest jdees1 running Port Test:Passed , UBE:Passed , BSFN:Passed
pyTest jdeais2 running Login:Passed , Form Service App:Passed , Form Service UBE:Passed
pyTest jdejas2 running Login:Passed , Interactive App:Passed , UBE:Passed
```

and this is what I am expecting.

```
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan='3'>dvTest</td>
            <td>jdeais1</td>
            <td>RUNNING</td>
            <td>Login:Passed , Form Service App:Passed , Form Service UBE:Passed</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>jdejas1</td>
            <td>RUNNING</td>
            <td>Login:Passed , Form Service App:Passed , Form Service UBE:Passed</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>jdees1</td>
            <td>RUNNING</td>
            <td>Login:Passed , Form Service App:Passed , Form Service UBE:Passed</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan='2'>pyTest</td>
            <td>jdeais2</td>
            <td>RUNNING</td>
            <td>Login:Passed , Form Service App:Passed , Form Service UBE:Passed</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>jdejas2</td>
            <td>RUNNING</td>
            <td>Login:Passed , Form Service App:Passed , Form Service UBE:Passed</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

These are just 5 records in reality it would be 500+

I am able to create a manual html table without rowspan based on RAW data, but need help for creating the html with rowspan based on dynamic rows.

Comment: what is the row span indicating? and what have you tried so far?

Comment: rowspan indicates the number of rows with similar first cell value for each row.
I was able to create a normal html table from the raw data but not the rowspan thing.
I tried using dictionaries but no luck. trying with JSON now.

Comment: if your raw output is stings couldn't you split those strings by the first space and then group the first string `dvTest` and preprocess to know how many they are in a row when you use them to create the HTML table?